# Java getResourceAsStream as local resource

Tags: java, textures, lwjgl, assets

Before using LWJGL, I used the `Graphic` method, and there I displayed `imageicons`, and I had the picture file located in the resources.
I used:

```
ImageIcon tcard = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("RCA.png"));
```

to load the image.

Now when I load textures in LWJGL, I have to use absolute paths to locate the file:

```
tcard = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG",  ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("C:/RCA.png"));
```

I tried Googling, but I didn't find anything helpful. How can I load the image from the local resources like in the first example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the class file you're running your code in as a reference. So if you have the file `RCA.png` in the root directory you would use:

```
tcard = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("RCA.png"));
```

Or if you were to have it inside an `art` directory in the root you would use:

```
TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/art/RCA.png"));
```